# How to implement/show following pop-over above textField?

Tags: ios, swift, textures, popover, toast

I m trying to implement following functionality in my iOS project.
Here is the screen,

[image]

If user do not enter anything or entered wrong data in email and mobile textFields, I want to show like this.

**Case 1**: If user didn't entered the email or entered incorrect email then it will show an message/view with "Enter valid Email Address"

**Case 2**: If user didn't entered the mobile number or entered incorrect mobile number then it will show an message/view with "Enter valid Mobile Number"

How to achieve this using swift?

Comment: One way is to create a uiview right above the textfields and keep their heights zero. When there is an error, you can animate them, by increasing their heights and making them visible. Use auto layout or storyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **`popoverPresentationController`** to get a `popover` on any of your `textFields`.

**1.** Create a `UIViewController` with a `UILabel` inside it.

```
class PopoverVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    var text: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textLabel.text = self.text
    }
}
```

[image]

**2.** In you `ViewController` create an instance of `PopoverVC` whenever you want to present the `message`. Present it as `popoverPresentationController` and pass the instance of `textField` over which you want to present the `message`, i.e.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverVC") as! PopoverVC
        controller.text = "Enter valid Mobile Number"
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300 , height: 70)

        let popover = controller.popoverPresentationController
        popover?.delegate = self
        popover?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
        popover?.sourceView = self.textField
        popover?.sourceRect = self.textField.bounds
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a **view** on top of them and set it hidden, and when the email is wrong. You could unhide the **view**.

Comment: The thing is that, I want to implement this feature in every ViewController wherever the forms are there. So this option is not a good choice for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess to show an underline and to show a small image at the right end in the UITextField you must have done subclassing of the UITextField. In the same subclass you can add the pop up view as subview and show and hide according your requirements from the delegate methods of UITextField.